# How to make Access primary key editable in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, gridview

I have set the `personel_no` field as primary key and setup update cascade at database level. In GridView's edit mode the primary key field is uneditable. How can I make that editable so that I can update the primary key alongside with other fields?

Comment: The field is not an AutoNumber but a String-typed field. Thank you Damien for the input.

Comment: if the Personel_no is Id, by scaffolding property it wont be editable in MVC. in ASp,net you need to use the textbox readonly.. or try label. or in The Edit screen you can use hidden text field .

Comment: Show the markup of gridview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make **personel_no** is editable. You can set the Readonly property to false in the Boundfield in Markup.

Example:-

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="personel_no" HeaderText="Personal Number" ReadOnly="False" 
                    SortExpression="personel_no" />
```

Comment: please read the question carefully! he wrote "How can I make that editable so that I can update the primary key alongside with other fields?" and you are suggesting him to make it readonly..he want to make it EDITABLE

Comment: do you think this will work? He has already mentioned that "Edit Mode" it means  their is some EditItemTemplate or some Popup! Do you mean using BOUNDFIELD he can EDIT the ROW?

Comment: Yes... using this property AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" and             AutoGenerateEditButton="True" in GridView. It will enable Edit/Delete Mode. Once you change the ReadOnly property to False all the fields in the table can edit in one shot. Before making a comment on anything, please check it in your end in sample application.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but This solution don't work.

Comment: still you are not able to edit the personel_no.. share me the gridview markup... use pastebin.com.. copy the only GridView markup..

Comment: you can check this link... http://www.sourcepod.com/aechim90-31237 .. Code is in C#.Net, I just used java highlight, let me know.